# Closing then opening standard input in C under Linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal, console

I have a C console application under Linux (Raspbian - Raspberry Pi). The program has some character animation - it prints out messages character by character. For example, the text

> Please give me your name!

is printed out completely after 5 seconds (char by char).

Afterwards, the user is asked to type in their name, which works just fine if the user waits for the message to be printed out. However, if the user is impatient and hits the keys on the keyboard randomly, the input request later is compromised.

Imagine the user types in

> abc\nefgh\n

while the above text is being echoed ('\n' means new line - enter). If that happens, the user will not be asked to properly type in his/her name, but the array of characters 'abc' will be accepted as input and gets validated.

My question is how to disable input (buffering) temorarily (on Linux). I have tried several methods and read numerous posts about doing so, but none of them worked for my purpose.

The function that is responsible for asking for input is as follows:

```
int getLine(char *s, int length)
{
    int i;
    char c;

    for (i = 0; i < length && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
    {
        if (c == '\0')
        {
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            s[i] = c;
        }
    }

    s[i] = '\0';

    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        c = getchar();
    }

    return i;
}
```

Empty lines are eliminated with the help of a while loop in the function calling the one above so enter inputs are considered invalid.

I tried closing stdin, but could not reopen it:

```
fclose(stdin);
```

and emptying buffer before the `getLine`:

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
while (c = fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL);
```

Unfortunately, it did not work as it does with text files.

`fflush(stdin);` did not work either and is not pretty anyway.

My goal is to prevent users from typing in anything while the text is being written out and to ignore/close input buffering (stdin) temporarily. Also, it would be great to disable outputting (flushing) user inputs during printing as it gets displayed on Linux terminal.

Comment: Doing `fflush(stdin)` is not only "not pretty", it's written in the C specification that it's *undefined*. Some libraries implement it as an extension, but generally you should not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do this by interacting with TTY directly. Look into source code of `passwd` or similar utilities for inspiration.

Function below clears TTY input buffer (error handling omitted). You need to call it just before reading user input.

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>

void clear_user_input() {
  if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO)) {
    int fd = open(ttyname(STDIN_FILENO), O_RDONLY);
    ioctl(fd, TCFLSH, TCIFLUSH);
    close(fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Is there a way I could disable printing out the characters that are typed in while the text is being echoed?

Comment: Look into manual page of `tcsetattr` -- you need to remove `ECHO` option. Seems that it may also be used to clear input buffer by using `TCIFLUSH`.